# Picturing SQL Reporting Services 2008 R2 Diagram Hierarchy

Tags: ssrs-2008, diagramming

Are there any tools out there to picture/diagram reports and subreports in a hierarchy?  We currently have around 50+ reports that are structured like this and I would like to build a visual picture.

At present I am looking through all of the xml in the files to get the Agent Ransack of course) which is taking a while.

I am debating on whether to write a little quick and dirty tool in C# WinForms that maybe automates Visio 2010 or try and take advantage of my Telerik components that I purchased.  I did come across this [Codeplex Visio Automation](http://visioautomation.codeplex.com/).  Any thoughts on these or any other diagramming tools that might help in my quest.

**Update**

I've started creating a .NET WinForm Application using [NShape](https://nshape.codeplex.com/) which looks like a reasonable diagramming object model.

Answer (score 0):

I did consider doing something similar myself but only spent an hour or so on it before other work commitments got in the way. However I did prototype a simple bit of code in LinqPad that takes the SSRS reports path and the rdl of the main report and returns all the sub reports.

It's not much but it may help you with your project in terms of getting the sub reports efficiently.

You could turn this into a simple app I guess but LinqPad makes life so much easier, get a free copy of it if you don't have it already and try this code.

```
void Main()
{
    string filePath = @"D:\Dev\SSRS Projects\MyReportsAreHerePath\";

    var x = XDocument.Load(filePath + @"MyMasterReportNameHere.rdl");
    var ns = x.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

    Func<string, report>getSubReports= null;
    getSubReports =
        fileName => new report
                    {
                    name = fileName, 
                    subReports = 
                    XDocument
                        .Load(filePath + fileName + ".rdl")
                        .Descendants(ns + "Subreport")
                        .Select(sr=>getSubReports(sr.Element(ns +     "ReportName").Value))
                    };

    getSubReports("MyMasterReportNameHere").Dump();



}


public class report
{
    public string name{get;set;}
    public float top { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<report> subReports {get;set;}
}
```

Regards,
Al

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I've knocked up a WinForm application that takes advantage of NShape.  Not using Linq - more XmlXPathDocument.  All is working fine, although the NShape support don't seem to great and documentation is incomplete although looks like a decent product.  I will post a like somewhere when I finish. it.